# How to retrieve String from DatagramPacket

Tags: java, android, udp, arrays

The following code prints

```
[B@40545a60,[B@40545a60abc exp
```

But I want to print `abc`, so that I can retrieve the correct message from the receiving system.

```
public class Operation {
InetAddress ip;
DatagramSocket dsock;
DatagramPacket pack1;
byte[] bin,bout;
WifyOperation(InetAddress Systemip)
{
    ip=Systemip;
    try {
        dsock=new DatagramSocket();

        } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

void sendbyte()
{
    String senddata="abc"; 
    bout=senddata.getBytes();
    pack1=new DatagramPacket(bout,bout.length,ip,3322);
    try {
        dsock.send(pack1);
        Log.d(pack1.getData().toString(),"abc exp");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

How can I retrieve string instead of byte from the packet `pack1`?

Comment: What output are you expecting and why?

Comment: i want to retrieve the original message "abc",which i added into the DatagramPacket,my problem is i cant retrieve  the string instead i getting its binary value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer based on comment:**

Indeed, my old answer was incorrect.
Update:

```
String str = new String(
    pack1.getData(),
    pack1.getOffset(),
    pack1.getLength(),
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8 // or some other charset
);
```

---

**Old answer:**

Do something like:

```
byte[] data = pack1.getData();
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(data), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (int value; (value = input.read()) != -1; )
    str.append((char) value);
```

This assumes the byte data represents (just) UTF-8 text, which may not be the case.

Comment: This ignores the transmitted length, and so it will give you a whole lot of trailing nulls. It's also five or six lines of code where one would do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:
`String msg = new String(pack1.getData(), pack1.getOffset(), pack1.getLength());`

Comment: Quite right, this is the correct answer.